# FFMPEG Output to DeckLink Duo 2

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

Im trying to use FFMPEG to stream out to my Decklink duo 2 but im unable to do so.

Heres the command that im trying:

```
ffmpeg -f decklink -i "DeckLink Duo (1)@5"
-pix_fmt uyvy422 -r 25000/1000 "DeckLink Duo (3)"
```

I tried just sending color bars as an output but it still doesnt work

Command:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=color=red -t 10000 "DeckLink Duo (3)"
```

Both Result:

```
ffmpeg version N-82794-g3ab1311 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads
 --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc 
--enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r 
--enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass 
--enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca 
--enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc 
--enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb 
--enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg 
--enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger 
--enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora 
--enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc 
--enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp 
--enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
 --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 42.100 / 55. 42.100
  libavcodec     57. 67.100 / 57. 67.100
  libavformat    57. 58.102 / 57. 58.102
  libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavfilter     6. 68.100 /  6. 68.100
  libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
Input #0, lavfi, from 'color=color=red':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc

[NULL @ 00000000025745a0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'DeckLink Duo (3)'
DeckLink Duo (3): Invalid argument
```

Any Suggestions or help to solve this is much appreciated.

Comment: At the very least, you need to include `-f decklink` before the output device name, Depending on Decklink's requirements, other arguments may be needed too.

Comment: @Mulvya I tried your suggestion and added -f decklink. Now i am receiving a different error


`[decklink @ 00000000024e4480] Could not enable video output!
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): I/O error`

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation says "DeckLink is very picky about the formats it supports. Pixel format is always uyvy422, framerate, field order and video size must be determined for your device with -list_formats 1. Audio sample rate is always 48 kHz.", see https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#decklink-1. So you need to add the resolution and make sure it is supported.

Comment: Hi i took your suggestion and tried it, with this code: 
`-f decklink -i "DeckLink Duo (2)@5" -pix_fmt uyvy422 -r 25000/1000 -s 1920x1080 -f decklink -r 25000/1000 -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt uyvy422 -vcodec copy -acodec copy "DeckLink Duo (3)"`
                                     And am receiving this error now : `[decklink @ 0000000000e9db40] Unsupported stream type.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): I/O error`

Comment: Why not start with the samples in the doc and work your way up from there? I can assure you they work as I use them myself. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

For the Duo 2 or Quad 2, You need to confirm in Desktop Video utility that you have assigned an SDI port to the channel, otherwise it may be in key/fill mode. This can be found in the third tab called "Connectors". If you can't select one (happens on device (2) or (4) if 1 or 3 are set to key/fill mode, you go back to 1 or 3 and change them to use a single connector.
That was the cause of my I/O error trying to use chanel (3).